# Is there a way to fetch the url from google search result when a csv file full of keyword is uploaded in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, filereader, google-search

Is it possible to obtain the url from Google search result page, given the keyword? Actually, I have a csv file that contains a lot of companies name. And I want there website which shows up on the top of search result in google, when I upload that csv file it fetch the company name/keyword and put it on the search field.

For eg: - **stack overflow**, this is one of the entry in my csv file and it should be fetched and put in the search field, and it should return the best match/first url from search result. Eg: - **www.stackoverflow.com**

And this returned result should be stored in the same file which I have uploaded and next to the keyword for it searched.

I am not aware much about these concepts, so any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

google package has one dependency on beautifulsoup which need to be installed first.

then install : 
**pip install google**

```
search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=None, pause=2.0)
```

**query** : query string that we want to search for.

**tld** : tld stands for top level domain which means we want to search our result on google.com or google.in or some other domain.

**lang** : lang stands for language.

**num** : Number of results we want.

**start** : First result to retrieve.

**stop** : Last result to retrieve. Use None to keep searching forever.

**pause** : Lapse to wait between HTTP requests. Lapse too short may cause Google to block your IP. Keeping significant lapse will make your program slow but its safe and better option.

**Return** : Generator (iterator) that yields found URLs. If the stop parameter is None the iterator will loop forever.

Below code is the solution for your question.

```
import pandas
from googlesearch import search 

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')

result = []
for i in range(len(df['keys'])):
    for j in search(df['keys'][i], tld="com", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
        result.append(j)

dict1 = {'keys': df['keys'], 'url': result}  
df = pandas.DataFrame(dict1) 
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

**Sample input format file image:**

[image: Sample input format file]

**Output File Image:**

[image]

Comment: In case a value in key column doesn't have a url (None in google search) would this work still? Or it would be nice if you embed a section which returns "no result" in url column.